# VueJS - The app cant locate the route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have all this pages working properly but the Signin one.
I have a compenent called Signin.vue, i added it to the route but when i try to reach it (http://localhost:8080/#/signin), the page just dont show anything.

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Contatos from '@/components/Contatos'
import NovoContato from '@/components/NovoContato'
import ViewContato from '@/components/ViewContato'
import EditarContato from '@/components/EditarContato'
import Signin from '@/components/Signin'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/cont',
      name: 'Contatos',
      component: Contatos
    },
    {
      path: '/novo_cont',
      name: 'NovoContato',
      component: NovoContato
    },
    {
      path: '/:contato_id',
      name: 'view-contato',
      component: ViewContato
    },
    {
      path: '/edit/:contato_id',
      name: 'editar-contato',
      component: EditarContato
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'Signin',
      component: Signin
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: is your console saying anything ? (f12) and can we see the signin component please ?

Comment: there's not enough info here to answer the question. Make sure you check your console logs and compile messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this path :

```
{
  path: '/:contato_id',
  name: 'view-contato',
  component: ViewContato
},
```

this path doesn't have a specific name, only a param which means all the routes defined after it in the router not work.

So you can put the `SignIn` route before the `ViewContato` route or specify a name to `ViewContato` route (`path: 'view/:contato_id'` for example)

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot!